# QT c++ application crash in single shot timer and connect

Tags: c++, qt, c++14

**MyFile.cpp**

```
MyFile::MyFile(QWidget *parent) :
                QWidget(parent),
                ui(new Ui::MyFile)
{
   ui->setupUi(this);      
   QTimer::singleShot(15000, this, SLOT(MyTreatment()));
   QObject::connect(&BlinkScreenTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(BlinkScreen()));
   BlinkScreenTimer.start(1000);
}

void MyFile::MyTreatment()
{
    BlinkScreenTimer.stop();
    qDebug() << __LINE__;
}

void MyFile::BlinkScreen()
{
  qDebug() << __LINE__;
}
```

**MyFile.h**

```
private:
    QTimer BlinkScreenTimer;

public slots:
    void BlinkScreen();
    void MyTreatment();
```

**Crash Log**

```
GNU gdb (Debian 7.12-6) 7.12.0.20161007-git
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /home/user/LZ_50/MyApplicationWithDebugSymbol...done.

warning: core file may not match specified executable file.
[New LWP 1674]
[New LWP 1682]
[New LWP 1684]
[New LWP 1683]
[New LWP 1690]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/home/user/LZ_50/MyApplicationWithDebugSymbol'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x76531ade in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Gui.so.5
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x72e4d000 (LWP 1674))]
(gdb)
```

**Back Trace of Application**

```
(gdb) 
(gdb) 
(gdb) 
(gdb) thread apply all bt full

Thread 5 (Thread 0x6850e3a0 (LWP 16409)):
#0  0x75b82730 in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
No locals.
#1  0x76cea89a in ?? () from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libglib-2.0.so.0
No symbol table info available.
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 4 (Thread 0x67b8c3a0 (LWP 16414)):
#0  0x75d9bbbe in nanosleep () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
No locals.
#1  0x7600056e in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#2  0x75f9f094 in QThread::msleep(unsigned long) () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Core.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#3  0x005432d6 in ?? ()
No symbol table info available.
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 3 (Thread 0x729ea3a0 (LWP 16407)):
#0  0x75b82730 in poll () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
No locals.
#1  0x732bdec4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libxcb.so.1
No symbol table info available.
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 2 (Thread 0x69ee63a0 (LWP 16408)):
#0  0x75b83914 in ioctl () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:84
No locals.
#1  0x753d72a0 in gcoOS_DeviceControl (Os=Os@entry=0x0, IoControlCode=IoControlCode@entry=30000, InputBuffer=InputBuffer@entry=0x69ee5be0, InputBufferSize=InputBufferSize@entry=400, 
    OutputBuffer=0x69ee5be8, OutputBufferSize=400) at /usr/src/debug/imx-gpu-viv/1_git-r0/git/driver/hal/os/linux/user/gc_hal_user_os.c:2655
        status = <optimized out>
        inputBuffer = 0x69ee5be0
        outputBuffer = 0x0
        args = {InputBuffer = 1777228776, InputBufferSize = 400, OutputBuffer = 1777228776, OutputBufferSize = 400}
        tls = 0x69500480
        logical = <optimized out>
        interrupt_count = 0
#2  0x753d8cf8 in gcoOS_WaitSignal (Os=Os@entry=0x0, Signal=<optimized out>, Wait=Wait@entry=4294967295) at /usr/src/debug/imx-gpu-viv/1_git-r0/git/driver/hal/os/linux/user/gc_hal_user_os.c:6721
        status = gcvSTATUS_NOT_OUR_INTERRUPT
        iface = {command = gcvHAL_USER_SIGNAL, hardwareType = gcvHARDWARE_2D, coreIndex = 0, status = gcvSTATUS_OK, handle = 8571388601093324800, pid = 1, engine = 1966074500, ignoreTLS = 0, u = {
            GetBaseAddress = {baseAddress = 3, flatMappingRangeCount = 1053, flatMappingRanges = {{start = 18446744071191813216, end = 8444274675986464769}, {start = 2706661561244593852, 
                  end = 84583170372009984}, {start = 8444225680965621972, end = 7633140468858338544}, {start = 12297829385900507136, end = 345527344076}, {start = 0, end = 0}, {start = 2706661559278501888, 
                  end = 0}, {start = 8444300688085638320, end = 7633140502999489744}, {start = 8571396591509724484, end = 8571980376349498584}, {start = 45, end = 5}, {start = 8571781998622801921, 
                  end = 0}, {start = 0, end = 8571782000618575880}, {start = 1995773960, end = 92525602}, {start = 8571782000588876420, end = 0}, {start = 0, end = 0}, {start = 0, end = 0}, {
                  start = 8444178932575502336, end = 995808}}}, QueryVideoMemory = {internalPhysical = 3, internalSize = 18446744071191813216, externalPhysical = 1, externalSize = 2706661561244593852, 
              contiguousPhysical = 0, contiguousSize = 8444225680965621972}, QueryChipIdentity = {chipModel = 3, chipRevision = 1053, chipDate = 1777228896, chipFeatures = 4294967295, 
              chipMinorFeatures = 1, chipMinorFeatures1 = 1966085908, chipMinorFeatures2 = 1966091964, chipMinorFeatures3 = 630193753, chipMinorFeatures4 = 0, chipMinorFeatures5 = 19693554, 
              chipMinorFeatures6 = 1966069972, streamCount = 1966074500, pixelPipes = 1995816176, resolvePipes = 1777229008, instructionCount = 1995816960, numConstants = 2863311531, 
              varyingsCount = 1929960396, gpuCoreCount = 80, productID = 0, chipFlags = (unknown: 0), ecoID = 0, customerID = 0}, MapMemory = {physical = 3, bytes = 18446744071191813216, 
              logical = 8444274675986464769}, UnmapMemory = {physical = 3, bytes = 18446744071191813216, logical = 8444274675986464769}, AllocateLinearVideoMemory = {bytes = 3, alignment = 1053, 
              type = 1777228896, flag = 4294967295, pool = gcvPOOL_DEFAULT, node = 1966085908}, AllocateVideoMemory = {width = 3, height = 1053, depth = 1777228896, format = 4294967295, 
              type = gcvSURF_INDEX, pool = 1966085908, node = 1966091964}, ReleaseVideoMemory = {node = 3}, LockVideoMemory = {node = 3, cacheable = 1053, address = 1777228896, 
              memory = 8444274675986464769, gid = 1966091964, physicalAddress = 84583170372009984}, UnlockVideoMemory = {node = 4522600562691, type = 1777228896, pool = 4294967295, bytes = 1, 
              asynchroneous = 1966085908}, AllocateNonPagedMemory = {bytes = 4522600562691, physical = 1777228896, logical = 8444274675986464769}, FreeNonPagedMemory = {bytes = 4522600562691, 
              physical = 1777228896, logical = 8444274675986464769}, AllocateVirtualCommandBuffer = {bytes = 4522600562691, physical = 1777228896, logical = 8444274675986464769}, 
            FreeVirtualCommandBuffer = {bytes = 4522600562691, physical = 1777228896, logical = 8444274675986464769}, Event = {queue = 4522600562691}, Commit = {context = 4522600562691, 
              commandBuffer = 18446744071191813216, delta = 8444274675986464769, deltas = {2706661561244593852, 84583170372009984, 8444225680965621972, 7633140468858338544, 12297829385900507136, 
                345527344076, 0, 0, 2706661559278501888, 0}, contexts = {8444300688085638320, 7633140502999489744, 8571396591509724484, 8571980376349498584, 45, 5, 8571781998622801921, 0, 0, 
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
                8571782000618575880}, commandBuffers = {1995773960, 92525602, 8571782000588876420, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8444178932575502336, 995808}, queue = 7633147959251572500, engine1 = 1777231968, 
              shared = 1, index = 0, count = 1995699043, commitStamp = 4294967296, contextSwitched = 5}, MapUserMemory = {memory = 4522600562691, physical = 1777228896, size = 8444274675986464769, 
              info = 1966091964, address = 630193753}, UnmapUserMemory = {memory = 4522600562691, size = 18446744071191813216, info = 1, address = 1966085908}, UserSignal = {command = gcvUSER_SIGNAL_WAIT, 
              id = 1053, manualReset = 1777228896, wait = 4294967295, state = 1}, Signal = {signal = 4522600562691, auxSignal = 18446744071191813216, process = 8444274675986464769, fromWhere = 1966091964}, 
            WriteData = {address = 3, data = 1053}, AllocateContiguousMemory = {bytes = 4522600562691, address = 1777228896, physical = 4294967295, logical = 8444274675986464769}, FreeContiguousMemory = {
              bytes = 4522600562691, physical = 1777228896, logical = 8444274675986464769}, ReadRegisterData = {address = 3, data = 1053}, WriteRegisterData = {address = 3, data = 1053}, 
            ReadRegisterDataEx = {address = 3, coreSelect = 1053, data = {1777228896, 4294967295, 1, 1966085908}}, WriteRegisterDataEx = {address = 3, coreSelect = 1053, data = {1777228896, 4294967295, 1, 
                1966085908}}, GetProfileSetting = {enable = 3}, SetProfileSetting = {enable = 3}, SetProfilerRegisterClear = {bclear = 3}, RegisterProfileData_part1 = {context = 3, Counters = {
                gpuTotalRead64BytesPerFrame = 1053, gpuTotalWrite64BytesPerFrame = 1777228896, fe_draw_count = 4294967295, fe_out_vertex_count = 1, fe_cache_miss_count = 1966085908, 
                fe_cache_lk_count = 1966091964, fe_stall_count = 630193753, fe_starve_count = 0, fe_process_count = 19693554, pe0_pixel_count_killed_by_color_pipe = 1966069972, 
                pe0_pixel_count_killed_by_depth_pipe = 1966074500, pe0_pixel_count_drawn_by_color_pipe = 1995816176, pe0_pixel_count_drawn_by_depth_pipe = 1777229008, 
                pe1_pixel_count_killed_by_color_pipe = 1995816960, pe1_pixel_count_killed_by_depth_pipe = 2863311531, pe1_pixel_count_drawn_by_color_pipe = 1929960396, 
                pe1_pixel_count_drawn_by_depth_pipe = 80, shader_cycle_count = 0, vs_shader_cycle_count = 0, ps_shader_cycle_count = 0, ps_inst_counter = 0, ps_rendered_pixel_counter = 0, 
                vs_inst_counter = 630193753, vs_rendered_vertice_counter = 0, vs_branch_inst_counter = 0, vs_texld_inst_counter = 1777228976, ps_branch_inst_counter = 1966091964, 
                ps_texld_inst_counter = 1777229008, vs_non_idle_starve_count = 1777229016, vs_starve_count = 1777229124, vs_stall_count = 1995683785, vs_process_count = 1777229016, 
                ps_non_idle_starve_count = 1995819708, ps_starve_count = 45, ps_stall_count = 0, ps_process_count = 5, pa_input_vtx_counter = 0, pa_input_prim_counter = 1, 
                pa_output_prim_counter = 1995773520, pa_depth_clipped_counter = 0, pa_trivial_rejected_counter = 0, pa_culled_prim_counter = 0, pa_droped_prim_counter = 0, 
                pa_frustum_clipped_prim_counter = 1995773960, pa_frustum_clipdroped_prim_counter = 1995773520, pa_non_idle_starve_count = 1995773960, pa_starve_count = 0, pa_stall_count = 92525602, 
                pa_process_count = 0, se_culled_triangle_count = 1966074500, se_culled_lines_count = 1995773520, se_clipped_triangle_count = 0, se_clipped_line_count = 0, se_starve_count = 0, 
                se_stall_count = 0, se_receive_triangle_count = 0, se_send_triangle_count = 0, se_receive_lines_count = 0, se_send_lines_count = 0, se_process_count = 0, se_trivial_rejected_line_count = 0, 
                se_non_idle_starve_count = 0, ra_input_prim_count = 1966063616, ra_total_quad_count = 995808, ra_valid_quad_count_after_early_z = 0, ra_valid_pixel_count_to_render = 1966085908, 
                ra_output_valid_quad_count = 1777230752, ra_output_valid_pixel_count = 1777231968, ra_pipe_cache_miss_counter = 1, ra_pipe_hz_cache_miss_counter = 0, 
                ra_prefetch_cache_miss_counter = 1995699043, ra_prefetch_hz_cache_miss_counter = 0, ra_eez_culled_counter = 1, ra_non_idle_starve_count = 5, ra_starve_count = 0, ra_stall_count = 0, 
                ra_process_count = 1966074500, tx_total_bilinear_requests = 39114960, tx_total_trilinear_requests = 39115024, tx_total_discarded_texture_requests = 39115168, tx_total_texture_requests = 0, 
                tx_mc0_miss_count = 0, tx_mc0_request_byte_count = 39114960, tx_mc1_miss_count = 39115024, tx_mc1_request_byte_count = 39115448, tx_non_idle_starve_count = 2863311531, tx_starve_count = 0, 
                tx_stall_count = 4294967281, tx_process_count = 0}}, RegisterProfileData_part2 = {context = 3, Counters = {mcc_total_read_req_8B_from_colorpipe = 1053, 
                mcc_total_read_req_8B_sentout_from_colorpipe = 1777228896, mcc_total_write_req_8B_from_colorpipe = 4294967295, mcc_total_read_req_sentout_from_colorpipe = 1, 
                mcc_total_write_req_from_colorpipe = 1966085908, mcc_total_read_req_8B_from_depthpipe = 1966091964, mcc_total_read_req_8B_sentout_from_depthpipe = 630193753, 
                mcc_total_write_req_8B_from_depthpipe = 0, mcc_total_read_req_sentout_from_depthpipe = 19693554, mcc_total_write_req_from_depthpipe = 1966069972, 
                mcc_total_read_req_8B_from_others = 1966074500, mcc_total_write_req_8B_from_others = 1995816176, mcc_total_read_req_from_others = 1777229008, mcc_total_write_req_from_others = 1995816960, 
                mcc_axi_total_latency = 2863311531, mcc_axi_sample_count = 1929960396, mcc_axi_max_latency = 80, mcc_axi_min_latency = 0, mc_fe_read_bandwidth = 0, mc_mmu_read_bandwidth = 0, 
                mc_blt_read_bandwidth = 0, mc_sh0_read_bandwidth = 0, mc_sh1_read_bandwidth = 630193753, mc_pe_write_bandwidth = 0, mc_blt_write_bandwidth = 0, mc_sh0_write_bandwidth = 1777228976, 
                mc_sh1_write_bandwidth = 1966091964, mcz_total_read_req_8B_from_colorpipe = 1777229008, mcz_total_read_req_8B_sentout_from_colorpipe = 1777229016, 
                mcz_total_write_req_8B_from_colorpipe = 1777229124, mcz_total_read_req_sentout_from_colorpipe = 1995683785, mcz_total_write_req_from_colorpipe = 1777229016, 
                mcz_total_read_req_8B_from_depthpipe = 1995819708, mcz_total_read_req_8B_sentout_from_depthpipe = 45, mcz_total_write_req_8B_from_depthpipe = 0, 
                mcz_total_read_req_sentout_from_depthpipe = 5, mcz_total_write_req_from_depthpipe = 0, mcz_total_read_req_8B_from_others = 1, mcz_total_write_req_8B_from_others = 1995773520, 
                mcz_total_read_req_from_others = 0, mcz_total_write_req_from_others = 0, mcz_axi_total_latency = 0, mcz_axi_sample_count = 0, mcz_axi_max_latency = 1995773960, 
                mcz_axi_min_latency = 1995773520, hi0_total_read_8B_count = 1995773960, hi0_total_write_8B_count = 0, hi0_total_read_request_count = 92525602, hi0_total_write_request_count = 0, 
                hi0_axi_cycles_read_request_stalled = 1966074500, hi0_axi_cycles_write_request_stalled = 1995773520, hi0_axi_cycles_write_data_stalled = 0, hi1_total_read_8B_count = 0, 
                hi1_total_write_8B_count = 0, hi1_total_read_request_count = 0, hi1_total_write_request_count = 0, hi1_axi_cycles_read_request_stalled = 0, hi1_axi_cycles_write_request_stalled = 0, 
                hi1_axi_cycles_write_data_stalled = 0, hi_total_cycle_count = 0, hi_total_idle_cycle_count = 0, hi_total_read_8B_count = 0, hi_total_write_8B_count = 1966063616, 
                l2_total_axi0_read_request_count = 995808, l2_total_axi1_read_request_count = 0, l2_total_axi0_write_request_count = 1966085908, l2_total_axi1_write_request_count = 1777230752, 
                l2_total_read_transactions_request_by_axi0 = 1777231968, l2_total_read_transactions_request_by_axi1 = 1, l2_total_write_transactions_request_by_axi0 = 0, 
                l2_total_write_transactions_request_by_axi1 = 1995699043, l2_axi0_minmax_latency = 0, l2_axi0_min_latency = 1, l2_axi0_max_latency = 5, l2_axi0_total_latency = 0, 
                l2_axi0_total_request_count = 0, l2_axi1_minmax_latency = 1966074500, l2_axi1_min_latency = 39114960, l2_axi1_max_latency = 39115024, l2_axi1_total_latency = 39115168, 
                l2_axi1_total_request_count = 0}}, RegisterProfileData2D = {hwProfile2D = 4522600562691}, SetPowerManagement = {state = gcvPOWER_SUSPEND}, QueryPowerManagement = {state = gcvPOWER_SUSPEND, 
              isIdle = 1053}, QueryKernelSettings = {settings = {signal = 3}}, MapPhysical = {map = 3, physical = 18446744071191813216}, Debug = {set = 3, level = 1053, zones = 1777228896, enable = -1, 
              type = gcvMESSAGE_DUMP, messageSize = 1966085908, 
              message = "\274.0uY\376\217%\000\000\000\000\362\177,\001\324\330/u\204\352/u\360\274\365v\320\\\356i\000\300\365v\253\252\252\252\314\333\bsP", '\000' <repeats 23 times>, "Y\376\217%\000\000\000\000\000\000\000"}, Cache = {operation = gcvCACHE_FLUSH, process = 18446744071191813216, logical = 8444274675986464769, bytes = 2706661561244593852, node = 0}, TimeStamp = {timer = 3, request = 1053, 
              timeDelta = 1777228896}, Database = {validProcessID = 3, processID = 1053, vidMem = {counters = {bytes = 18446744071191813216, maxBytes = 8444274675986464769, 
                  totalBytes = 2706661561244593852, allocCount = 0, freeCount = 19693554}, time = 8444225680965621972}, nonPaged = {counters = {bytes = 7633140468858338544, maxBytes = 12297829385900507136, 
                  totalBytes = 345527344076, allocCount = 0, freeCount = 0}, time = 0}, contiguous = {counters = {bytes = 2706661559278501888, maxBytes = 0, totalBytes = 8444300688085638320, 
                  allocCount = 1777229008, freeCount = 1777229016}, time = 8571396591509724484}, gpuIdle = {counters = {bytes = 8571980376349498584, maxBytes = 45, totalBytes = 5, allocCount = 1, 
                  freeCount = 1995773520}, time = 0}, vidMemPool = {{counters = {bytes = 0, maxBytes = 8571782000618575880, totalBytes = 1995773960, allocCount = 92525602, freeCount = 0}, 
                  time = 8571782000588876420}, {counters = {bytes = 0, maxBytes = 0, totalBytes = 0, allocCount = 0, freeCount = 0}, time = 0}, {counters = {bytes = 8444178932575502336, maxBytes = 995808, 
                    totalBytes = 7633147959251572500, allocCount = 1777231968, freeCount = 1}, time = 8571462122343497728}}}, Version = {major = 3, minor = 1053, patch = 1777228896, build = 4294967295}, 
            ChipInfo = {count = 3, types = {1053, 1777228896, 4294967295, gcvHARDWARE_3D, 1966085908, 1966091964, 630193753, gcvHARDWARE_INVALID, 19693554, 1966069972}, ids = {1966074500, 1995816176, 
                1777229008, 1995816960, 2863311531, 1929960396, 80, 0, 0, 0}}, Attach = {context = 3, maxState = 18446744071191813216, numStates = 1, map = 1966085908, physicals = {1966091964, 630193753}, 
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
              logicals = {84583170372009984, 8444225680965621972}, bytes = 1995816176}, Detach = {context = 3}, GetFrameInfo = {frameInfo = 4522600562691}, SetTimeOut = {timeOut = 3}, VGCommit = {
              context = 4522600562691, queue = 18446744071191813216, entryCount = 1, taskTable = 2706661561244593852}, QueryCommandBuffer = {information = {feBufferInt = 3, tsOverflowInt = 1053, 
                addressMask = 1777228896, addressAlignment = 4294967295, commandAlignment = 1, stateCommandSize = 1966085908, restartCommandSize = 1966091964, fetchCommandSize = 630193753, 
                callCommandSize = 0, returnCommandSize = 19693554, eventCommandSize = 1966069972, endCommandSize = 1966074500, staticTailSize = 1995816176, dynamicTailSize = 1777229008}}, SetFscaleValue = {
              value = 3}, GetFscaleValue = {value = 3, minValue = 1053, maxValue = 1777228896}, ExportVideoMemory = {node = 3, flags = 1053, fd = 1777228896}, NameVideoMemory = {handle = 3, name = 1053}, 
            ImportVideoMemory = {name = 3, handle = 1053}, QueryResetTimeStamp = {timeStamp = 4522600562691, contextID = 18446744071191813216}, CreateNativeFence = {signal = 4522600562691, 
              fenceFD = 1777228896}, WaitNativeFence = {fenceFD = 3, timeout = 1053}, DestroyMmu = {mmu = 4522600562691}, ShBuf = {command = gcvSHBUF_WRITE, id = 18446744071191813216, 
              data = 8444274675986464769, bytes = 1966091964}, GetGraphicBufferFd = {node = {3, 1053, 1777228896}, shBuf = 8444274675986464769, signal = 1966091964, fd = 630193753}, SetVidMemMetadata = {
              node = 3, readback = 1053, ts_fd = 1777228896, fc_enabled = 4294967295, fc_value = 1, fc_value_upper = 1966085908, compressed = 1966091964, compress_format = 630193753}, GetVideoMemoryFd = {
              handle = 3, fd = 1053}, ConfigPowerManagement = {enable = 3}, WrapUserMemory = {desc = {flag = 3, handle = 1053, dmabuf = 18446744071191813216, logical = 8444274675986464769, 
                physical = 1966091964, size = 630193753, externalMemoryInfo = {allocatorName = "\000\000\000\000\362\177,\001\324\330/u\204\352/u\360\274\365v\320\\\356i\000\300\365v\253\252\252\252", 
                  userData = {1929960396, 80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 630193753}}}, node = 0, bytes = 8444300688085638320}, WaitFence = {handle = 3, timeOut = 1053}, CommitDone = {context = 4522600562691}, 
            BottomHalfUnlockVideoMemory = {node = 3, type = 1053}, QueryChipOptions = {gpuProfiler = 3, allowFastClear = 1053, powerManagement = 1777228896, enableMMU = -1, 
              allowCompression = gcvCOMPRESSION_OPTION_COLOR, uscL1CacheRatio = 1966085908, secureMode = (unknown: 1966091964)}}}
#3  0x7531845c in gcoBufferCommitWorker (ThreadData=0x254d910) at /usr/src/debug/imx-gpu-viv/1_git-r0/git/driver/hal/user/gc_hal_user_buffer.c:1212
        i = 0
        bStop = 0
        currWorker = <optimized out>
        deltaWorker = <optimized out>
        commitWorker = 0x254d910
#4  0x75d945d8 in start_thread (arg=0x0) at pthread_create.c:458
        pd = 0x0
        unwind_buf = {cancel_jmp_buf = {{jmp_buf = {-449406527, -117341756, 1777230752, 2129674880, 2, 1777229232, 1927680000, 0 <repeats 57 times>}, mask_was_saved = 0}}, priv = {pad = {0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 
              0x0}, data = {prev = 0x0, cleanup = 0x0, canceltype = 0}}}
        not_first_call = <optimized out>
        pagesize_m1 = <optimized out>
        sp = <optimized out>
        freesize = <optimized out>
        __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ = "start_thread"
#5  0x75b886fa in ?? () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/arm/clone.S:76 from /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
No locals.
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)

Thread 1 (Thread 0x72e61000 (LWP 16399)):
#0  0x76545ade in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Gui.so.5
No symbol table info available.
#1  0x76545ada in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Gui.so.5
No symbol table info available.
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

My application crash **randomly**. My Code is as per above. My Application control didn't reach at Line No print of function **MyTreatment** and **BlinkScreen** when the application is crash.
I have compiled the application with debug symbol on and from that found address of */usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Gui.so.5* which is outside of my application.
Is this problem of QT-Framework or something happening in the application.

Comment: Install the debug symbols for Qt, then do `bt` in `gdb`. There is stuff you are not showing. There is at least a call to `ui->setupUi` missing, and you should not have an instance of the UI per widget, it's a factory and there should be only a single instance.

Comment: PS: You should not be using the Qt4 style `SIGNAL` / `SLOT` macros. They provide no type safety, and a mismatching signature will cause a crash at runtime. Use the modern syntax with function pointers.

Comment: Programs crash and so programmer has to learn to debug it, We can only help to explain why some little example program, that is fully posted here, crashes. We can not figure why your undisclosed program crashes.

Comment: @ÖöTiib Thanks for the comment. We need guidance from a person like you. If you have any suggestions related to code it's really welcome from me and it really helps full for me for. I cant not put my whole application here.. So for that, I put code snippets and debug log.. and from debug log i have found that there is a crash from/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Gui.so.5 which makes me curious that is it bug from qt fream work.

Comment: @Ext3h Although, I agree in general concerning Qt5 signals, I consider the slots `void BlinkScreen();` and `void MyTreatment();` as compatible to [QTimer::timeout()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html). Btw. crash? I thought it's a notification on console (and slot ignored) but I must admit I've less to no experience with Qt4 style signals. However, I suspect something else. A [mcve] would be nice to justify this encompassing.

Comment: You can also use QtCreator to compile, deploy and remote debug your code, it might make it easier to pinpoint where exactly it goes wrong.

Comment: @user3559721 it is possible but extremely unlikely that the defect itself in Qt library as programmers of it know how to debug. It is far more likely that your code corrupts some data passed to it and so it crashes. Your low debugging skill is indicated by fact that it tells that Qt5Gui crashes in undisclosed location. Apparently you have not linked with debug library.

Comment: @ÖöTiib there is plenty of hinden-bug situations created by Qt's design itself. One of possible crashes on calling slots is incompatibility of signatures. Another is race condition or fact that object for which slot was called was `delete`d during handling another slot function.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie yes, that is what I mean by corrupting. Deleting data that is not up to user to delete, or passing incompatible things, or just failing with whatever kind of buffer sizes or pointer arithmetics ... the opportunities to do it are totally endless. It is not design flaw as in C++ no library can protect itself against misuse.

Comment: @ÖöTiib If the crash happened due to application then it addresses we got in the crash log. Currently, the crash happens in from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Gui.so.5 what does it mean. Is it a bug in the library itself or miss-use of some library function.  So if i ahve any miss use how to detect that part? Thanks for comment

Comment: @user3559721 it means that the crash happens somewhere in library. Where exactly is unknown as library does not have debug symbols. It is your responsibility to achieve that you debug with debug library.

Comment: @user3559721 you have to backtrace it using postmortem debugging in gdb (google that, there were instructions on SO and SU) to see where that call stack started in your program, but it might be complicated if stack is corrupted. gcc got an option  of stack protector which retains copy of call stack at cost of performance (it's a debug\bug hunting option). Debug symbols for library not required if problem source is in your code. But even it that case crash could happen because of bug existing in code executed prior to that (e.g. going out of array bounds)

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Thanks for the guidance it really gives me a chance to explore new things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from debug log `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Gui.so.5`  mins QT libreary crash.
QT library crash when you break some rule of qt library.
Check you previously used slot if you use `delete this`
then use **deleteLater()**.
Here stack fream corrupt due to use of `delete this` inside slot.